# Java / Javascript - Get the ip from the client

Tags: java, javascript, heroku, ip, playframework-2.0

I am using java playframework2 and it seems that I can not get the correct ip address with it. It constantly changes after each request.

I mean traffic analytic sites implement javascript in your header to analyse your traffic, so it should be possible with javascript right?

- If the framework doesn't provide such a function are there other ways to get the ip from the client?
- I want to build a visitor counter, but it should only count unique visitors. Maybe I don't have to use the ip address?

I know that there is http://jsonip.appspot.com/ but it's to unreliable. I couldn't use it the last 2 days because it had exceeded its quota on google app engine.

here is my code

```
public static <T> void increaseViews(String title, String ip,
        Class<T> objClass) throws UnknownHostException, MongoException,
        DbAuthException {
    Logger.info("Ip address: " + ip);
    String ipCache = title + "-" + ip;
    if (Cache.get(ipCache) == null) {
        Cache.set(ipCache, "block", 86400);
        increment(title, objClass);
    }

}

private static <T> void increment(String title, Class<T> objClass)
        throws UnknownHostException, MongoException, DbAuthException {
    // update database
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
UserGuides.increaseViews(ug.title, request().remoteAddress(),
                UserGuides.class);
```

If I follow the logs on Heroku, my ip address is different everytime I reload the page.

Comment: It is possible to get the ip address with the play framework, perhaps you should show us some of what you are trying to do with the code.

Comment: I have added an answer that will hopefully address your issue without requiring extra work to implement a secondary ip detection system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku will not directly return the remote address to your play application. Instead what you are seeing is various internal load balancing servers that are part of heroku. However, the good news is that you can easily fix this as per: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/705-remoteaddress-seems-to-get-dynamically-client-ip-on-heroku

Simply put: add this to your application.conf

```
trustxforwarded=true
```

Comment: Okay nice this is working. Just one question I get two ip address now something like `"ip-address, another-ip-address"` What is the second ip address and should I delete it?

Answer (score 3):

For JavaScript, we need jQuery Lib, and **EasyJquery** JS. This API is fast, and return full information.

```
<!-- Require jQuery / Anyversion --><script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Require EasyJQuery After JQuery --><script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://api.easyjquery.com/easyjquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
    // 1. Your Data Here
    function my_callback(json) {
        alert("IP :" + json.IP + " nCOUNTRY: " + json.COUNTRY);
    }

    function my_callback2(json) {
        // more information at http://api.easyjquery.com/test/demo-ip.php
        alert("IP :" + json.IP + " nCOUNTRY: " + json.COUNTRY + " City: " + json.cityName + " regionName: " + json.regionName);
    }

    // 2. Setup Callback Function
   // EasyjQuery_Get_IP("my_callback"); // fastest version
    EasyjQuery_Get_IP("my_callback2","full"); // full version
</script>
```

EasyjQuery use `JSONP`, so you need a callback function(json). You can call function `EasyjQuery_Get_IP(“your_callback_function”)` any time. This is information return from request:

```
[IP] => 93.154.204.208
[continentCode] => NA
[continentName] => North America
[countryCode2] => US
[COUNTRY] => US
[countryCode3] => USA
[countryName] => United States
[regionName] => California
[cityName] => Garden Grove
[cityLatitude] => 33.7877
[cityLongitude] => -117.9738
[countryLatitude] => 38
[countryLongitude] => -98
[localTimeZone] => America/Los_Angeles
[localTime] => 03:33:28 am
```

***[Here](http://api.easyjquery.com/test/demo-ip.html)*** is a live Working Demo.